Не работает импорт модуля по абсолютному пути в python
Структура проекта такая:
my_project
|
|___database
|   |
    |___api
    |   |
    |   |___db_api.py
    |
    |___models
    |   |
    |   |__film
    |   |_user
        |_recomendation


Я запуская скрипт  db_api в котором модули из папки  models импортируются так
from database.models.film import Film
from database.models.user import User
from database.models.recomendation import Recomendation

И я получаю ошибку
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'database'
  File "/home/vor/vscode_WS/db_sqlalchemy_practice/database/api/database_api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from database.models.film import Film
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

Я знаю, что относительные пути нельзя использовать в скриптах, которые непосредственно запускаются, но я использую абсолютный! В чем проблема, подскажите?

Так у вас models на том же уровне, что и database. Зачем тогда вы пытаетесь попасть в models, через database?! Толи я чего-то не понимаю..

Как запускаете код, как пакет или как отдельный скрипт?

db_api.py запускаю как отдельный скрипт

Тогда абсолютный импорт не будет тоже работать. Запускайте как пакет, типа python -m database.api.db_api

Сорян, изначально неправильно изобразилась структуру проекта. сейчас я исправила и ошибка должна воспроизводиться

Я и не видел, какая там структура проекта раньше у вас была. В любом случае и абсолютный, и относительный импорты работают только при запуске кода как пакета.

Абсолютный импорт точно так же как и относительный работает только внутри пакета, т.е. чтобы работало, нужно запускать командой python -m database.api.db_api из корня проекта.
Когда вы запускаете модуль как скрипт, импорт вида from database.models.film import Film для интерпретатора Python означает, что в папке со скриптом (либо по какому-то из путей из переменной окружения PYTHONPATH) должен находиться пакет (папка) database, в нем пакет models, в нем модуль film, и из модуля уже нужно импортировать класс Film. Интерпретатор в этом случае не смотрит на уровни выше, а смотрит только в папке скрипта и папках из PYTHONPATH.
Если запускать db_api как модуль из пакета, то интерпретатор поймет, что мы находимся в пакете database. И что в этом же пакете нужно искать, то что мы импортируем, в данном случае по абсолютному импорту от "корня" пакета, а не от директории, запускаемый модуль находится.
Можно, конечно, добавить корень проекта в PYTHONPATH, но это костыльное решение. Нормальное решение — запускать как пакет.

Для упрощения запуска можно в корень проекта (рядом с папкой database) добавить "пусковой" скрипт, в нем импортировать db_api. Предположим, что в db_api у вас есть функция main, ее запуск идет в блоке if __name__ == "__main__": (код не стартует просто при импорте). Тогда в пусковом файле пишем что-то типа:
from database.api.db_api import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Если в db_api пусковой код не в if __name__ == "__main__":, то он сработает просто при импорте, дополнительно вызывать ничего не нужно будет. Но я бы не советовал так оставлять, лучше спрятать код в этот блок, а в корневом пусковом файле явно запускать то что вам нужно ("явное лучше неявного").

спасибо! Хорошего вам дня

Есть несколько способов решения такой проблемы:
$PYTHONPATH
В Python вы можете создать (или обновить) переменную окружения PYTHOPATH, работает она так же как и стандартная системная переменная $PATH, только если $PATH указывает где искать пути к исполняемым файлам, PYTHONPATH указывает пути к пакетам питона. Особенно удобно это может быть при испоьзовании virtualenv, ведь вы можете добавить экспорт этой переменной в скрипт активации виртуальной среды, примерно так:
export PYTHONPATH=/home/artur1214/ptest/my_project && python3 db_api.py

(структура проекта:)

Кстати, почти наверняка в Pycharm ваш код бы работал, потому что он автоматически добавляет к PYTHONPATH путь до текущего проекта.
Но такой способ очень неудобен:
Придется придется постоянно разбираться как правильно настроить PYTHONPATH при переносе на новый компьютер или просто переносе проекта в другую папку.
Запуск из файла.
Создайте в корне проекта условный main.py
from database.api.db_api import *
#...код

При этом вы импорты будут работать. Основной код вы можете продолжать писать внутри db_api, или (лучше) перенести тесты в main.py, а в db_api оставить только логику модуля api
Если совсем невмоготу, вы можете написать в самом верху db_api вот такой код:
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))

Он добавляет в системный список путей путь до корня проекта относительно db_api.py. (По сути то же самое, что PYTHONPATH, только из питона) Но на мой взгляд это полукостыльное решение.

спасибо! Хорошего вам дня

возможно, не так понял вопрос, но, может, мой ответ чем то поможет:
По Вашей структуре получается, что в database у вас действительно нет директории models, она находится в my_project. Возможно, вот так нужно сделать импорт:
from my_project.models.film import Film

Я бы сделал классический пакет с файлом __unit__.py, и туда бы напихал все импорты.
примерно:


Извините, я поздно ночью неправильно изобразила структуру проекта. Database хранит models
